# Enabling a GameObject by refering to its name from a txt file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I tried to save a gamestate (which gameobject is enabled) by writing a string to a txt file. And yes this works, now I would like to load it from that txt file.

I tried enabling the gameobject and refering from the txt file but it won't work. (The name 'LoadGameObject' does not exist in the current context)

```
   public string Data;


public void LoadData()
{
    StreamReader LoadWriter = new StreamReader("Assets/SaveData/Savefile.txt");
    //LoadWriter.ReadLine();
    //Data = File.ReadAllText("Assets/SaveData/Savefile.txt");
    Data = LoadWriter.ReadLine();
    print(Data);
    GameObject.Find("Level").transform.Find(Data);
    GameObject.SetActive(true);
```

}

I expect to enable the gameobject which is read from the file.

Comment: Your StreamWriter, LoadWriter, does not seem to be used. I suggest either removing `Data = File.ReadAllText("Assets/SaveData/Savefile.txt");` and chaging `LoadWriter.ReadLine();` to `Data = LoadWriter.ReadLine();` _**or**_ removing your StreamReader. You should also try printing data `print(data);`

Comment: Well I tried it, even delete the LoadGameObject, but still not good

Comment: When you `print(data);`, what does it print?

Comment: Well I cannot startup the game because of the compile error

Comment: Change `LoadGameObject = GameObject.Find(Data);` to `GameObject LoadGameObject = GameObject.Find(Data);`

Comment: But I disabled the problem and I tried and it prints what it's in the txt file.

Comment: I tried it and there is no compile error, but there is an ingame error
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: I just remembered, GameObject.Find does not work on inactive GameObjects

Comment: Then how should I find it? :(

Comment: If you put all your GameObjects that may need to be activated under a GameObject,  (name it `Level` or something), then you can use `GameObject.Find("Level").transform.Find(data).gameObject;`

Comment: Still needs a reference...

Comment: Can you post the code you are using now?

Comment: I've edited it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GameObject is a class, you can make a variable of the type GameObject (in this example, it is called temp).
Try this:

```
public string Data;

public void LoadData()
{
    StreamReader LoadWriter = new StreamReader("Assets/SaveData/Savefile.txt");
    //LoadWriter.ReadLine();
    //Data = File.ReadAllText("Assets/SaveData/Savefile.txt");
    Data = LoadWriter.ReadLine();
    print(Data);
    GameObject temp = GameObject.Find("Level").transform.Find(Data).gameObject;
    temp.SetActive(true);
}
```

Edit: added `.gameObject` to temp's declaration

Comment: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'
Another one bites the dust.